# Jasmine $location test

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, jasmine

I try to test $location service. 
This is my controller

```
var recordType = $location.search().recordType;
```

And my test:

```
describe('CorrectCtrl', function() {

var scope, httpMock;
var location, rootScope;
beforeEach(module('mainApp'));
beforeEach(inject(function($controller, $timeout, $location, $rootScope) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    location = $location;
    rootScope = $rootScope;
    ctrl = $controller('myCtrl', {
        $scope : scope,
        $location : location
    });
}));

it('location test', function(){
    location.path("/PATH/");
    location.search('recordType', '1');
    expect(this.recordType).toBe('1');
});
```

How can I set my controller values using `$location` mock?
I want to make sure that redordType is set to 1;

Answer (score 1):

Try to call $rootScope.$digest() before expect function call

Comment: It does't work. Got same error: Expected undefined to be '1'.